# Git commit hook to run in windows (auto JIRA prefix)

Tags: git, batch-file, git-commit

I want to write a batch file as a commit hook to check if the users are adding the JIRA ID as a prefix to the commit message.

I have already created scripts but those are working only in the Linux environment only.

I was unable to find any sample for such.

Comment: What's your question? SO isn't a code writing service; try to port them yourself and let us know where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try the very latest Git for Windows (the [`Git-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/Git-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.exe) setup)

As documented in [issues 130](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/130):

A most typical use case is for e.g. GitHub for Windows to start a Git Bash in a given working directory.

> I changed the behavior of `git-bash.exe` to require the new `--cd-to-home` option to behave like the Git Bash start menu item (which uses that option now).
>
> The default is to not switch directory explicitly. If you want to switch to the home directory (as was the default of `git-bash.exe` before), you have to pass the `--cd-to-home` option.

It means that the contextual menu should work. And that now, the comamnd-line command `git-bash.exe` does work too (it opens a bash in the current folder)

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same:

- In `.git\hooks` create a file named `prepare-commit-msg.bat`
- Edit the file and write `echo JIRA-12345 >> %2` (change to whatever JIRA ID)
- I only use [tortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) so it's much easier to configue Git Hooks:

  1. Make sure that Arrow `#3` is set to your project's directory
  2. `#4` select your script and on the top right corner select when should it run.
  3. Checked "wait for the script to finish" if you would like that.

[image]

---

The only problem left, is when I `Pull` from the repo, it automatically merges if there were any changes and write a commit message without the JIRA ID, so I must manually Amend last commit and fix it after a Pull.